# Undefined name '_selectedDay'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
Undefined name '_selectedDay'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime?'.
```

> I just followed a package called table calendar, where I have followed the code listed and implemented it in my project but something is missing from the code. even though I copied it from github. so on '_selectedDay' what to do

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code that is giving that error.  It's difficult to figure out what the actual issue is without any specific details, like  what your code is like.  How you're using this github code, etc..

Answer (score 1):

The example code of that package is from

https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/basics_example.dart

`_selectedDay` is something you need to define yourself.